# why does git erase the token for github in .git-credentials?

Tags: git, github, credentials

I have configured my git credentials to store:

```
$ git config credential.helper
store
```

and written my github token into `.git-credentials` like so:

```
echo "https://$gitUser:$githubToken@github.com" > ~/.git-credentials
```

When I now try to clone a repository from github, I get the following error message:

```
bash-4.4$   git clone https://github.com/$gitUser/$gitRepo
Cloning into '...' ... remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13,
2021. remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/.../.../'
```

After the unsuccessful clone, the entry in `.git-credentials` is erased. Why is that? I assume the error message to be related to the erasing of the entry.

Comment: Try using the "--global" flag, "git config --global credential.helper"

Comment: Github does not support password authentication anymore. Use a token instead. The password is considered invalid. The entry is removed by Git as designed. If the invalid password is kept, every time it needs authentication, a request destinated to fail is sent to the server. After several unsuccessful attempts, it may trigger some safety mechanism. The server could lock the account for a while. Besides, it reminds the user to offer a valid phrase.